# Help with a vector-spinor equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, spinors

**How can I show that the equation**
$$\gamma^{abc}\partial_{b}\psi_c=0$$
**leads to** 
$$\partial_{b}\psi_{c}-\partial_{c}\psi_{b}=0?$$
I know that 
$$\gamma^{abc}= \frac{1}{2}\{ \gamma^{a}, \gamma^{bc} \}$$
which can be written as
$$\gamma^{abc}= \frac{1}{2} ( \gamma^{a}\gamma^{bc} + \gamma^{bc}\gamma^a )$$
which is the same as
$$\gamma^{abc} = \frac{1}{4}( \gamma^{a}\gamma^{b}\gamma^{c}-\gamma^{a}\gamma^{c}\gamma^{b}+\gamma^{b}\gamma^{c}\gamma^{a}-\gamma^{c}\gamma^{b}\gamma^{a}) $$
but then when I plug the spinor in I dont see how I am supposed to get my result.

Comment: I presume $\gamma^{bc} = [\gamma^b,\gamma^c]$. Therefore this object is antisymmetric in the indices. Decompose $\partial_b\psi_c$ into symmetric and antisymmetric part. The former projects to 0 under contraction with $\gamma^{abc}$ and therefore you're left with only the antisymmetric part, i.e. $\frac12(\partial_b\psi_c - \partial_c\psi_b)$.

Comment: yes, $\gamma^{bc} = 1/2 [\gamma^{b},\gamma^c]$. But I am not sure what you re suggesting. The part about the projection to 0. I know that a symmetric in two indices tensor times an antisymmetric in the same indices tensor is zero but I am not sure how it applied here.

Comment: The same way: $\gamma^{abc}$ is antisymmetric in $bc$ so if $T_{bc} = S_{bc} + A_{bc}$ is a generic tensor and its sym/antisym decomposition, $\gamma^{abc}T_{bc} = \gamma^{abc}A_{bc}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma^{abc}$ is antisymmetric in $ab$, you can write

$\gamma^{abc} \partial_b \psi_c = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^{abc}-\gamma^{acb}) \partial_b \psi_c \ .$

Now $a$ and $b$ are dummy indices, i.e. they are summed over, so we can rename them to get

$\gamma^{abc} \partial_a \psi_c = \frac{1}{2}\gamma^{abc}(\partial_b \psi_c - \partial_c \psi_b) \overset{.}{=} 0 \ ,$

which is true for either $\gamma^{abc}=0$ or $\partial_b \psi_c - \partial_c \psi_b= 0$. Since it has to be true for all $\gamma^{abc}$ the latter is true, which is exactly the identity you were looking for.